# When should I use a precondition and when to include another use-case to provide those conditions?

Tags: use-case, include

For example, suppose '*Borrwoing a book*' a use case:

I can figure out two description for it:

Description one:

- **Precondition:** The member to access this use-case should be already logged in.
- OR EVEN **Precondition:** The book id should be specified.
- Enter the book id
- ....

Description two:

- Include the `Login` use-case
- OR Include the `Search the book by title` use-case
- Enter the book id
- ....

However here, it seems the first approach is better, but is there any general rule for it?
Could they be two way for writing a use-case?

Answer (score 1):

Use cases should already identify the type of user (a logged-in user is a type of user, as is an administrator or some other role like sales clerk).

> As a logged in user, I need the ability to request a book by title.

Comment: Then, it might my example wasn't good, I modified it to another example, what about that?

Comment: Don't complicate your use cases.  Use cases are not programming; they are part of the requirements gathering process.  Your customer doesn't care about "preconditions;" just state your use case clearly in plain English, and include the precondition in the description, as I have done.